# How can I make an element stick to the top of the screen when scrolling

Tags: css, sticky

I have two divs, the first is long and floated left so the second smaller one sits to the top right of it. Neither are at the top of the screen. The second div is a quick links panel allowing user to jump to specific points in the first div. I want the second div to remain in its position when scrolling until it hits the top of the screen and then to stick whilst the rest of the page continues scrolling and then to  return to its starting position when the user scrolls back down. I have tried the usual position: sticky, top: 0 on the second div, but this is having no effect. The code is written in React.

The basic markup then is essentially:

```
<style>
   .div1 { float: left }
   .div2 { position: sticky; top: 0 }
</style>

<div>
   <div class="div1">
      ......
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
       .....
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did one of the answers below solve your problem? If so, please accept one of them using the green check mark. It lets the answerers know that your problem has been solved. If not, please expand on what problems you are continuing to have.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use `display:flex` on the parent instead of using `float`.
`top` refers to the parent element, so first of all that needs to overflow.

Here is an example where the main element has `height: 200vh`.

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: flex;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  color: white;
  background: #349;
  height: 200vh;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

.div2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  height: 100vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="div1">
    Teflon
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    Sticky
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that is **none** of the parents of your stiky element has property *overflow: hidden;*.

Maybe it won't help, but it is a useful tip.